# How to prove $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f:X \to Y$. $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ . Prove the following:

Prove that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$ also give an example where $f(f^{-1}(B))\neq B$.

My Request:

If possible please do give a little bit detailed answer with intuition since I am beginner in Proofs.

Answer (score 3):

I will prove (1); you can use a similar argument to prove (2).

*Proof*.
Let $X\subseteq A$ and let $x\in X$ be given.
Then $f(x)\in f(X)$.
Recall that for a set $Y\subseteq B$, we define
$$
f^{-1}(Y) = \{y\in A\mid f(y) \in Y\}
$$
Since $f(x)\in f(X)$, it follows that $x\in f^{-1}(f(X))$.
By the arbitrary choice of $x\in X$, we conclude that $X\subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.